# A confusion about the impossibility of perpetual motion

Tags: thermodynamics, perpetual-motion

It is stated that

> If any engine could produce a greater amount of work than that
>   produced by a reversible cyclic heat engine, then it was possible to
>   produce work endlessly by the following means. Begin by moving heat
>   from the hot reservoir to a cold reservoir using the more efficient
>   engine. Then move the same amount of heat back to the hot reservoir
>   using the reversible engine. Because the forward process does more
>   work than is needed to perform the reverse process, there is a net
>   gain in work. In this cycle of operations, a certain amount of heat
>   was simply moved from the hot to the cold reservoir and back to the
>   hot reservoir, with a net gain of work. By repeating this cycle, an
>   unlimited amount of work can be obtained simply by moving a certain
>   amount of heat back and forth between a hot and a cold reservoir.

However, the generation of a net gain of work would take a finite time and since the net gain is also finite, you can never produce an infinite amount of work. Moreover, I cannot see how it is related to "perpetual motion"; if the engine was requiring a finite amount of work, say $W_0$, to complete the cycle once, and the net work gain is $W_1$, as long as $W_1 < W_0$, the engine cannot continue working with the net gain of work that itself creates, so just by the quoted argument, one cannot prove the non-existance of a heat engine with a net gain $W_1 < W_0$.

Am I missing something in here?

Answer (score 1):

They say unlimited, not infinite. Unlimited means you can repeat the process as many times as you wish.

For reversible engine, it is possible when going from state $A$ to $B$ by producing work $W_0$ to revert back from $B$ to $A$ by using work $W_0$, so the the net work produced is zero and you are back in precisely the same state as the one you started with. But if you used more efficient engine to go from state $A$ to state $B$, you would gain work $W_1>W_0$. Now you use reversible engine to return to state $A$ for which you need to use $W_0$ amount of work, but the net work produced by the whole cycle $A\rightarrow B\rightarrow A$ would be $W_1-W_0$. If this is positive, it means you were able to return to the same state as before, while simultaneously gaining energy. In reality however, when you gain energy, it is impossible to return back to the same state.

In the case of the quote state $A$ would be the initial state of reservoars and $B$ would be the state of reservoars after the first heat transfer by efficient engine.